# Gauge theory for mathematicians?

Tags: differential-geometry, resource-recommendations, gauge-theory, yang-mills, category-theory

I'm looking for a textbook or set of lecture notes on gauge theory for mathematicians that assumes only minimal background in physics. I'd prefer a text that uses more sophisticated mathematical concepts like principal bundles and connections, and categorical language whenever convenient.

Comment: [Google is your friend...](https://www.google.de/search?q=gauge+theory+for+mathematicians&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=m-gvVtXsE8GMsAHd8YrIBA)

Comment: Check out _"Gauge fields, knots and gravity"_ by Baez and Munian. I think it strikes a nice balance between mathematical formalism and physical intuition.

Comment: You might see "Gauge Fields Knots and Gravity" by John Baez and Javier Munian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have been writing something in this direction in section 1 of the book *Differential cohomology in a Cohesive topos* ([pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12630719/dcct.pdf)). Have a look, just focus on section 1 and ignore the remaining sections on first reading.

The survey-part is presently also appearing as a series on PhysicsForums. See at *[Higher prequantum geometry I](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/higher-prequantum-geometry-need-prequantum-geometry/)*, *[II](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/higher-prequantum-geometry-ii-principle-extremal-action-comonadically/)*, *[III](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/higher-prequantum-geometry-iii-global-action-functional-cohomologically/)*, *[IV](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/higher-prequantum-geometry-iv-covariant-phase-space-transgressively/)*, *[V](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/higher-prequantum-geometry-v-local-observables-lie-theoretically/)* and *[Examples of Prequantum Field Theories I -- Gauge fields](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/examples-prequantum-field-theories-gauge-fields/)*, *[II -- Higher gauge fields](https://www.physicsforums.com/insights/examples-prequantum-field-theories-ii-higher-gauge-fields/)*.

Comment: Please don't edit away the link to the pdf (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12630719/dcct.pdf). It's more comprehensive. I will update the arXiv version soon.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I just have a question: you say on page 4 that the curvature of a connection is a cocycle in nonabelian differential cohomology. I'm only familiar with the basics of the Chern-Weil homomorphism and characteristic classes, but it seems to me that the curvature is not in general a closed form. Is there some other sense in which the curvature form is a cocycle?

Comment: Which page 4 do you mean? Abelian curvatures are closed, otherwise the evaluation of the curvature in a characteristic polynomial is closed.

Comment: The book looks amazing.

Answer (score 4):

One less well-known but great reference are the classical field theory notes by **Deligne and Freed** in the ['99 IAS lectures](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821820125). Some good things about them

- Very elegant treatment written for mathematicians
- Begins with a nice discussion of ordinary classical mechanics using principal bundles and connections
- Useful comments on supersymmetric gauge theories throughout.