Gauge Theory: Mathematics + Physics
I'm interested in learning mathematical gauge theory, particularly its applications in physics, focusing on (topological) quantum field theory with an emphasis on condensed matter.
I'm looking for mathematically precise references that are rich in physical examples. Do you know of any books, notes, or papers that fit this description? I'm open to consulting multiple sources but would like to start with the most comprehensive set available.

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/214966/2451 and links therein.
